# how to correctly use append function in sqlite3 database in swift 4

Tags: swift

I am creating a login/signup form and storing the email(the id),name, age,gender   using the following code:

```
while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
    let email = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0))
    let name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
    let age = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2)
    let gender = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))

    userList.append(email: String(email),name:String(name),age: Int(age),gender: String(gender))
}
```

however,I am getting the error:Extra argument 'name' in call 
I have been googling for 2 days. Can you please help me? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the definition of `userList`?

Comment: var userList = [user]().   It is a list of users ,and I have created a class user containing the mentioned fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the initialization of your `user` object.

```
userList.append(user(email: email, name: name, age: age, gender: gender))
```

Note that you don't have to build new strings from existing strings (and Ints).

Also note that by convention, type names in Swift are spelled with initial caps, so your class should be called `User`, not `user`.